# Using Javascript to submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, forms

im working on a project using mvc asp.net and what i try to do now is to submit a form using javascript.

the javascript works and submit my form.

My problem is that i have a value in my button tag which i want get in my controller but its only null.

the controller is correct because if i do a normal submit without javascript i get the value i want from
my `<button>`

using javascript i only receive null.

someone can give me a hand with this pls??

thanks in advance

**Here is my code:**

```
 $(function () {
        $('form').find('button[type=submit]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $form = $(this).closest('form');
            if (this.name == 'yes') {
                doConfirm("Confirm that you want to validate?", function yes() {
                    $form.submit();
                });
            } else {
                doReject("Confirm that you want reject?", function no() {
                    // do nothing
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you please add the HTML code?

Comment: where you placed the button? inside form?

Comment: hey guys.. see my update html code above pls

Comment: Which button value do you need in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically submitted forms don't include a parameter corresponding to a submit button, which makes sense considering they weren't directly triggered by clicking a button. The easiest way would be to add the corresponding parameter to the `action` property of the form prior to submitting it. Something like this should work:

```
var button = this;
...
doConfirm("Confirm that you want to validate?", function yes() {    
    $form[0].action += ($form[0].action.indexOf('?') != -1 '&' : '?') + button.name + '=' + button.value;
    $form.submit();
}
```

Alternatively you could turn the entire thing into an AJAX submit, and include the corresponding parameter along with the other form data.